# I am not able to use <gather> in my webhook code where the routing is done when a voice call comes on the twilio number

Tags: twilio

I want to get what the user speaks on voice call to my Twilio number. Please help me how can I use the  to get what user speaks on call in my node.js code?

```
 const express = require('express');
 const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;

 const app = express();
 app.post('/voice', (request, response) => {

const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

const gather = twiml.gather({
    input: 'speech',
    action: '/completed'
});
gather.say('Welcome, please tell us why you\'re calling');

console.log(response.toString());
});
app.listen(3004,function(){
console.log("Server Started");
});
```

When I call on my Twilio number I get application error occurred on the call.

Comment: What's the error if you check on Twilio's debugger? (https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/debugger?quickDate=24)

Comment: I get 11205 HTTP connection failure when i Call on my Twilio number

Comment: you have code for `app.post('/voice'...` but you don't have `app.post('/completed'...` so add another section `app.post('/completed', (request, response) => { // your code here});`

Comment: I have added but still it says the same error app.post('/completed', (request, response) => {
    console.log(request.toString());});

Comment: Heyooo. :) It looks like you're not responding the actual response. According to the docs you have to do `response.send()`. https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.post.method Also make sure that you set a proper content type `application/xml`. :) Hope that helps.